# How to make TextFields and RaisedButton the same width?

Tags: flutter

I have a simple login page with username and password and a login button. The problem is RaisedButton is a bit wider than the TextFields and that looks bad.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:freekade/home.dart';

const _padding = EdgeInsets.all(16.0);
const _elevation = 16.0;

final _inputKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'username');

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  String _username = '';
  String _password = '';
  bool _showValidationError = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final username = Padding(
        padding: _padding,
        child: TextField(
          key: _inputKey,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
              errorText: _showValidationError ? 'Username Invalid' : null,
              labelText: 'Username',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
              )),
          onChanged: _updateUsername,
        ));

    final password = Padding(
      padding: _padding,
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
          errorText: _showValidationError ? 'Password Invalid' : null,
          labelText: 'Password',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
          ),
        ),
        obscureText: true,
      ),
    );

    final loginButton = ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      child: RaisedButton(
        padding: _padding,
        elevation: _elevation,
        child: Text('Log In'),
        onPressed: _loginUser,
      ),
    );

    final loginForm = Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: 400,
          child: ListView(
        children: [
          username,
          password,
          loginButton,
        ],
      )),
    );

    return Padding(
      padding: _padding,
      child: loginForm,
    );
  }

  void _updateUsername(String value) {
    setState(() {
      _username = value;
    });
  }

  void _loginUser() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
      builder: (context) {
        return HomeScreen();
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

I tried wrapping a Container with a specific width around the ListView, but then `width` (in Container) seems to accept only double-type hard-coded width and further, the button sticks out yet (See screenshot). How can I make them all the same width preferably without much hard-setting width values?

[image]

Comment: A short piece of advice: try to avoid splitting the widgets into properties in the build(..) method. It makes the code less readable as you have to jump back and forth through the method in order to understand whats happening. If your widget becomes too verbose, split it into seperate widgets.

Comment: Great advice. Thank you @Herry. Since, almost everything is a widget in flutter, it seems just fine to use them in-place rather than putting them in properties first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding you gave to you gave to the `RaisedButton` are applied within it and not outside the `RaisedButton`.

You can fix it by wrapping the `RaisedButton` with a `Padding`.

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```
  final loginButton = ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        child: Padding( // new line
          padding: _padding, // new line [ gives button outer padding ]
          child: RaisedButton(
            padding: _padding, // inner padding 
            elevation: _elevation,
            child: Text('Log In'),
            onPressed: _loginUser,
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Read more about the `Padding` class here: [Padding class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

You assign a padding to your `RaisedButton`. The `Padding` in there only applies to the content of the button, in your case the `Text` "Login" as it is stated in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html).

So to get the same width of all widgets in the ListView, you would have to assign a seperate `Padding` to the RaisedButton like so:

```
Padding(
    padding: _padding,
    child: RaisedButton(
        padding: _padding,
        elevation: _elevation,
        child: Text('Log In'),
        onPressed: _loginUser,
    ),
)
```